# How to use Flask-Cache with Flask-Restful

Tags: python, redis, flask-restful, flask-cache, cache-invalidation

How do I use Flask-Cache @cache.cached() decorator with Flask-Restful? For example, I have a class Foo inherited from Resource, and Foo has get, post, put, and delete methods.

How can I can invalidate cached results after a `POST`?

```
@api.resource('/whatever')
class Foo(Resource):
    @cache.cached(timeout=10)
    def get(self):
        return expensive_db_operation()

    def post(self):
        update_db_here()

        ## How do I invalidate the value cached in get()?
        return something_useful()
```

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `Flask-Cache` implementation doesn't give you access to the underlying `cache` object, you'll have to explicitly instantiate a `Redis` client and use it's `keys` method (list all cache keys).

- The `cache_key` method is used to override the default key generation in your `cache.cached` decorator.
- The `clear_cache` method will clear only the portion of the cache corresponding to the current resource.

**This is a solution that was tested only for `Redis` and the implementation will probably differ a little when using a different cache engine.**

```
from app import cache # The Flask-Cache object
from config import CACHE_REDIS_HOST, CACHE_REDIS_PORT # The Flask-Cache config
from redis import Redis
from flask import request
import urllib

redis_client = Redis(CACHE_REDIS_HOST, CACHE_REDIS_PORT)

def cache_key():
   args = request.args
   key = request.path + '?' + urllib.urlencode([
     (k, v) for k in sorted(args) for v in sorted(args.getlist(k))
   ])
   return key

@api.resource('/whatever')
class Foo(Resource):

    @cache.cached(timeout=10, key_prefix=cache_key)
    def get(self):
        return expensive_db_operation()

    def post(self):
        update_db_here()
        self.clear_cache()
        return something_useful()

    def clear_cache(self):
        # Note: we have to use the Redis client to delete key by prefix,
        # so we can't use the 'cache' Flask extension for this one.
        key_prefix = request.path
        keys = [key for key in redis_client.keys() if key.startswith(key_prefix)]
        nkeys = len(keys)
        for key in keys:
            redis_client.delete(key)
        if nkeys > 0:
            log.info("Cleared %s cache keys" % nkeys)
            log.info(keys)
```

Comment: This worked for me with a couple of caveats. One, flask-caching prepends `flask_cache_` to the key_prefix (configurable as "CACHE_KEY_PREFIX". See: https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-caching/blob/cb6a7a3d61057b07ebdc7a58359b41257fe0af93/flask_caching/__init__.py#L188), so I just added that to clear_cache. Additionally, the redis_client needed to be StrictRedis with decode_responses=True otherwise the key.startswith was byte instead of string, which threw errors.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use like that.

Maybe you will still need to read: [flask-cache memoize URL query string parameters as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413566/flask-cache-memoize-url-query-string-parameters-as-well)

Answer (score 2):

You can invalidate cache using `cache.clear()` method.
For more detials see: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.clear and Clearing Cache section in https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/

Comment: Doesn't calling clear() remove ALL cache contents?  I am interested in selectively removing items from the cache when a POST request is made.

Comment: Have you found any way of doing this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Matias, look at my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

```
##create a decarator
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
CACHE_TIMEOUT = 300
cache = SimpleCache()
class cached(object):

 def __init__(self, timeout=None):
    self.timeout = timeout or CACHE_TIMEOUT

 def __call__(self, f):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        response = cache.get(request.path)
        if response is None:
            response = f(*args, **kwargs)
            cache.set(request.path, response, self.timeout)
        return response
    return decorator


#add this decarator to your views like below
@app.route('/buildingTotal',endpoint='buildingTotal') 
@cached()
def eventAlert():
  return 'something'

@app.route('/buildingTenants',endpoint='buildingTenants')
@cached()
def buildingTenants():
  return 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @JahMyst didn't work for me.
Flask-Cache doesn’t work with Flask restful framework.  @cache.Cached & @cache.memoize can’t handle mutable objects per their documentation.

```
Using mutable objects (classes, etc) as part of the cache key can become tricky. It is suggested to not pass in an object instance into a memoized function. However, the memoize does perform a repr() on the passed in arguments so that if the object has a __repr__ function that returns a uniquely identifying string for that object, that will be used as part of the cache key.
```

Had to come-up with my own implementation. Leaving this code snippet incase someone else gets stuck with the same issue.

`cache_key` function converts the user req into hash.
`cache_res_pickled` function is being used to pickle or unpickle the data

```
|-flask-app
   |-app.py
   |-resource
      |--some_resource.py
```

```
import json
import logging
import pickle
import time
import urllib

from flask import Response, abort, request
from redis import Redis

redis_client = Redis("127.0.0.1", "6379")
exp_setting_s = 1500


def json_serial(obj):
    """
    JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"
    Args:
            obj: JSON serialized object for dates

    Returns:
            serialized JSON data
    """
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return obj.__str__()


def cache_key():
    """ ""
    Returns: Hashed string of request made by the user.

    """
    args = request.args
    key = (
        request.path
        + "?"
        + urllib.parse.urlencode(
            [(k, v) for k in sorted(args) for v in sorted(args.getlist(k))]
        )
    )
    key_hashed = hashlib.sha256(key.encode())
    return key_hashed.hexdigest()


def cache_res_pickled(data, encode):
    """
    Args:
        data (dict): Data in dict format
        encode (Boolean): Encode (true) or decode (false) the data

    Returns: Result after pickling
    """
    if encode:
        return pickle.dumps(data)
    else:
        data = pickle.loads(data)
        return data


class SomeResource(Resource):
    @auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        # Get the key for request in hashed format SHA256
        key = cache_key()
        result = redis_client.get(key)

        def generate():
            """
            A lagging generator to stream JSON so we don't have to hold everything in memory
            This is a little tricky, as we need to omit the last comma to make valid JSON,
            thus we use a lagging generator, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630320/
            """
            releases = res.__iter__()
            try:
                prev_release = next(releases)  # get first result
                # We have some releases. First, yield the opening json
                yield '{"data": ['
                # Iterate over the releases
                for release in releases:
                    yield json.dumps(prev_release, default=json_serial) + ", "
                    prev_release = release
                logging.info(f"For {key} # records returned = {len(res)}")
                # Now yield the last iteration without comma but with the closing brackets
                yield json.dumps(prev_release, default=json_serial) + "]}"
            except StopIteration:
                # StopIteration here means the length was zero, so yield a valid releases doc and stop
                logging.info(f"For {key} # records returned = {len(res)}")
                yield '{"data": []}'

        if result is None:
            # Secure a key on Redis server.
            redis_client.set(key, cache_res_pickled({}, True), ex=exp_setting_s)

            try:
                # Do the querying to the DB or math here to get res. It should be in dict format as shown below
                res = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 2}
                # Update the key on Redis server with the latest data
                redis_client.set(key, cache_res_pickled(res, True), ex=exp_setting_s)
                return Response(generate(), content_type="application/json")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)
                abort(505, description="Resource not found. error - {}".format(e))
        else:
            res = cache_res_pickled(result, False)
            if res:
                logging.info(
                    f"The data already exists! loading the data form Redis cache for Key - {key} "
                )
                return Response(generate(), content_type="application/json")
            else:
                logging.info(
                    f"There is already a request for this key. But there is no data in it. Key: {key}."
                )
                s = time.time()
                counter = 0
                # loops aimlessly till the data is available on the Redis
                while not any(res):
                    result = redis_client.get(key)
                    res = cache_res_pickled(result, False)
                    counter += 1
                logging.info(
                    f"The data was available after {time.time() - s} seconds. Had to loop {counter} times.‍"
                )
                return Response(generate(), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score -1):

Inspired from durga's answer I wrote a very basic decorator which uses redis directly instead of any library.

```
from src.consts import config
from src.utils.external_services import redis_connector
import json
import jsons
import base64


class cached(object):

    def __init__(self, req, timeout=None):
        self.timeout = timeout or config.CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
        self.request = req
        self.cache = redis_connector.get_redis_instance()

    def __call__(self, f):
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):

            redis_healthy = True
            if self.cache is not None:
                try:
                    self.cache.ping()
                except Exception as ex:
                    redis_healthy = False
            else:
                redis_healthy = False

            if self.request is not None and self.request.values is not None and self.request.path is not None and redis_healthy:
                cache_key = "{}-{}".format(self.request.path, json.dumps(jsons.dump(self.request.values), sort_keys=True))
                cache_key_base_64 = base64.b64encode(cache_key.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")

                response = self.cache.get(cache_key_base_64)
                if response is None:
                    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.cache.setex(cache_key_base_64, self.timeout, jsons.dumps(response))
                else:
                    response = json.loads(response)
            else:
                response = f(*args, **kwargs)

            return response

        return decorator
```

Now use this decorator on your api functions

```
from flask import g, request
from flask_restful import Resource
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args

class GetProducts(Resource):
    @use_args(gen_args.argsGetProducts)
    @cached(request)
    def get(self, args):
        return "hello from products"
```