# Flask cache memoize not working with flask restful resources

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-restful, flask-cache

`flask_cache.Cache.memoize` not working with `flask_restful.Resource`

Here is sample code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cache import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})


class MyResource(Resource):
    JSONIFY = True
    PATH = None
    ENDPOINT = None

    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kw = dict(**kwargs)
        kw.update(request.args.items())
        r = super().dispatch_request(*args, **kw)
        if self.JSONIFY:
            return jsonify(r)
        else:
            return r


class DebugResource(MyResource):
    PATH = '/debug'
    ENDPOINT = 'debug'

    @cache.memoize(timeout=30)
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        print('cache is not used!')
        return kwargs

for r in [DebugResource]:
    api.add_resource(r, r.PATH, endpoint=r.ENDPOINT)


print('running!')
app.run()
```

Notice that in `get()` I added print so I can see when the code is actually called and when cached value is used.

I start server then in browser i go to `http://localhost:5000/debug?a=1`
and press `f5` repeatetely. I expect that my function `get` is called once and then cached value is used. But in server console I see my print each time I press `f5`. So `memoize` is not working. What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

I moved my cached function outside from `Resource` class

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=30)
def my_foo(a):
    print('cache is not used!')
    return dict(kw=a, id=id(a))

class DebugResource(MyResource):
    PATH = '/debug'
    ENDPOINT = 'debug'

    def get(self, a):
        return my_foo(a)
```

and that worked. As far as I can see, the issue was `self` argument that was actually unique in each call.
The question is still, how to make it work without extracting additional function for each method i want to cache? Current solution looks like a workaround.

Comment: I don't know who clicked `downvote` for your question, but I don't understand why you clicked `downvote` for my answer. I wanted to help and I'm sure my solution is working. Could you explain why you did it?

Comment: Sorry for that, I clicked `downvote` because wasn't what I expected, though you solution will work. I'd like to change my vote back but I'm not alloved to until you edit you answer.My point was that I want my cache to take function args into account and only them. So I can decorate resource methods and any other function with the same way. So it is not suitable for me when cache uses `request.path` as key instead on args. And the problem was that arg `self`affects cache key calculation and makes it unique every request.

Comment: Can you make rollback `downvote`? I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. good luck in development ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank @Rugnar, this decision came in handy.

### [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42808800/3178060)

The only point, I had to change it a bit, so that I would not exclude the first element (self), but use it, in order to store more unique keys in a situation where the cached method is defined in the base class, and in the children they are customized.

Method `_extract_self_arg` updated.

```
class ResourceCache(Cache):
""" When the class method is being memoized,
    cache key uses the class name from self or cls."""

def _memoize_make_cache_key(self, make_name=None, timeout=None):
    def make_cache_key(f, *args, **kwargs):
        fname, _ = function_namespace(f)
        if callable(make_name):
            altfname = make_name(fname)
        else:
            altfname = fname
        updated = altfname + json.dumps(dict(
            args=self._extract_self_arg(f, args),
            kwargs=kwargs), sort_keys=True)
        return b64encode(
            md5(updated.encode('utf-8')).digest()
        )[:16].decode('utf-8')

    return make_cache_key

@staticmethod
def _extract_self_arg(f, args):
    argspec_args = inspect.getargspec(f).args

    if argspec_args and argspec_args[0] in ('self', 'cls'):
        if hasattr(args[0], '__name__'):
            return (args[0].__name__,) + args[1:]
        return (args[0].__class__.__name__,) + args[1:]
    return args
```

Maybe it will also be useful to someone.

Comment: what if I'm using @staticmethod and remove the self in the get() method? this breaks the code, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

The cache doesn't work because you use [memoize](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.memoize) method. In this case it will cache the result of a function. Decorator doesn't know anything about route(view, path).

To fix it you should use [cached](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.cached) method. `@cached` decorator has argument `key_prefix` with default value = `view/request.path`.

So, just change `@cache.memoize(timeout=30)` to `@cache.cached(timeout=30)`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because memoize [takes function's arguments into account in the cache key](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.memoize) and every new request gets unique `kwargs` (unique result of `id` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)).

To see, simply modify the code

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=30)
def get(self, **kwargs):
    print('cache is not used!')
    return id(kwargs)
```

and every new request you will get another result. So every new request **cache key is different**, that's why you see `cache is not used!` on the console output.

Comment: using `**kwargs` is not good solution, because other developers will not see signature of function. input data will be like a black box.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I am not saying it's a good practice, that's only an OP's code and I used this to describe why cache "doesn't work".

Comment: I tried this, `id` is not changed, but the problem is still

`@cache.memoize(timeout=30)`
`def get(self, a):`
`print('cache is not used!')`
`return dict(kw=a, id=id(a))`

Comment: @Rugnar Just use `@cache.cached` as Danila Ganchar has suggested and define callable `key_prefix`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14264116/3866610

Answer (score -1):

Found solution by subclassing `Cache` and overloading logic that creates cache key for `memoize`. So it works fine.

```
import json
import inspect
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import md5
from flask_cache import Cache, function_namespace

class ResourceCache(Cache):
    def _memoize_make_cache_key(self, make_name=None, timeout=None):
        def make_cache_key(f, *args, **kwargs):
            fname, _ = function_namespace(f)
            if callable(make_name):
                altfname = make_name(fname)
            else:
                altfname = fname

            updated = altfname + json.dumps(dict(
                args=self._extract_self_arg(f, args),
                kwargs=kwargs), sort_keys=True)

            return b64encode(
                md5(updated.encode('utf-8')).digest()
            )[:16].decode('utf-8')

        return make_cache_key

    @staticmethod
    def _extract_self_arg(f, args):
        argspec_args = inspect.getargspec(f).args
        if argspec_args and argspec_args[0] in ('self', 'cls'):
            return args[1:]
        return args
```

In other words, when class method is being memoized, cache ignores the first argument `self` or `cls`.